# Can the hadoop file system api write to a relative local file path?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

For testing purposes we would like to write to a *relative* local path like `target/pipelines`.  The attempted `URI` was

```
 file://target/pipelines/output.parquet
```

which was accessed via `Spark`:

```
if (!FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration).exists(new Path(path))) {
```

However the `hadoop filesystem` api does not seem too keen on that:

```
Wrong FS: file://target/pipelines/inputData1, expected: file:///
```

Full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    Wrong FS: file://target/pipelines/inputData1, expected: file:///
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:649)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.pathToFile(RawLocalFileSystem.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:824)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1426)
    at com.mycompany.DataFrameUtils$.generateParquetFile(DataFrameUtils.scala:71)
```

So is it not possible to write to a local relative path ?

Answer (score 0):

For accessing local file system using Hadoop API, you have to use either single /  or / three times after colon

`file:/target/pipelines/output.parquet`

or

`file:///target/pipelines/output.parquet`

In order to use the relative path (pwd), If it's through the command line - below command should work.

```
hadoop  fs -Dfs.defaultFS="file:/" -ls  testdir
```

If you want to use the same in the Scala or Java application, You need to set the below config in the driver code, take out `file:///` from the path variable, Just give relative path.

```
conf.set("fs.defaultFS","file:/");  # Hadoop Configuration Object.
```

In Spark this configuration can be over ridden in the spark-submit command line using --conf option and take out `file:///` from the path variable, Just give relative path.

```
./bin/spark-submit
  --conf fs.defaultFS="file:/" \
  --class <main-class> \
  --master <master-url> \
  --deploy-mode <deploy-mode> \
  ... # other options
  <application-jar> \
```

Comment: Both of those do the same thing - and are absolute paths.  I'm assuming then there were no relative paths available..?

Comment: Do you want to use `pwd` as relative path - Prefix ?

Comment: `file:/` is *not* a relative path : (I wondered myself and tried it out..)

Comment: file:/ is the file system type.. not the path

Comment: *try it out* please: the result is an absolute path.